# Different background color for left and right with content that entends to the bottom edge

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I am trying to set up a page that has two background colors. One color for the left half of the page and another for the right half of the page and content that sits in the middle that is centered horizontally. If the content in the page does not fill the entire browser window vertically, the content ends and I can see the two background colors below it. Is there a way to extend the content vertically to always fill the browser window? I know [sticky footers](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) works well, but I can't seem to get it to work with what I am doing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer footer footer</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
#left, #right {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#left {
    background: #014c8d;
    left: 0;
}
#right {
    background: #0f2451;
    right: 0;
}
#container {
    background: #fff;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: #006d46;
}
#footer {
    background: #006d46;
    position: relative;
}
```

I have a jsfiddle to show what I currently have: http://jsfiddle.net/snPYb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add height:100%; to your `wrapper` and `html,body` :

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; 
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background: #006d46;
    height:100%;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/snPYb/2/)

**EDIT #1 :**

Try this :

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; 
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
}
```

Added `display:table` and `width:100%`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/snPYb/5/)**

Comment: That works, but if the content is longer than the browser bad things happen. http://jsfiddle.net/snPYb/4/

Comment: Actually, min-height works if the content is too large (it pushes the footer down), but it does not work if the content is not tall enough to fill the browser. Any other thoughts?

Comment: This does work in Chrome, Safari and Opera. Firefox and IE don't push the content down to the bottom still.

Comment: This works on firefox, but is inconsistent on other browsers. No worries, I've implemented a jquery fix that assigns the height to the content when the page loads and on resize and it seems to be a good solution. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/snPYb/3/

What you were missing was the `height:100%` on the wrapper as well.

Comment: That works as long as the content is shorter than the browser window. Once the content has to be scrolled, it breaks.

Comment: Change "height" on both the body and the container to "min-height"

http://jsfiddle.net/snPYb/7/

Comment: min-height works if the content is too long, but if the content doesn't fill the page, the footer doesn't get pushed down. I have since created a jQuery solution and it works, but curious if there is a pure CSS solution.